# How to submit same form two times?

Tags: forms, jsf, primefaces, submit

I have to say, that I am not sure is that a problem, but I think so. I have a from where is two submit buttons. With first one I fetch product infos via serial number and with two I submit the whole form again.

Search button and code:

**BUTTON 1**

```
<p:column><h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.newRma_label_sarjanumero}" for="sarjanro" /></p:column>
                <p:column><p:inputText id="sarjanro" value="#{MainController.selected.sarjanro}" style="width: 200px;" /></p:column>
                <p:column><p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search"
                                           action="#{MainController.haeTiedotSarjanrolla}" style="width: 100px;" update=":messagePanel"/></p:column>

 //Fetching product info with serial number
public String haeTiedotSarjanrolla() {
    log.info("sarjanro=" + current.getSarjanro());
    Sarjanumerot s = null;

    s = helper.getSerialInfo(current.getSarjanro());
    if (s != null) {
        current.setAn8(s.getAn8());
        current.setDsc1(s.getDsc1());
        current.setDsc2(s.getDsc2());
        current.setSarjanro(s.getId().getLotn());
        current.setTuotenro(s.getId().getLitm());
    }

    // Back to same page!
    return "newRma";
}
```

**Another button (save)**

```
<p:column><p:commandButton action="#{MainController.talletaUusiRma}" value="#{bundle.newRma_tallenna}" immediate="true" style="width: 220px;"/></p:column>
```

Save (Button 2) is working, BUT request is empty, there is not any data. I tried to check it like that and it is always NULL:

another field what is not populated after first submit:

```
<p:row>
            <p:column></p:column>
            <p:column><p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.newRma_shortdesc}" for="shortdesc"/></p:column>
            <p:column><p:inputTextarea rows="4" cols="30" id="shortdesc" value="#{MainController.selected.shortdesc}" style="width: 200px;"/></p:column>

        </p:row>

Map<String, String> parameterMap = (Map<String, String>) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                     .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String temp = parameterMap.get("shortdesc");
```

temp is always NULL!!

Is there any best practise to handle this with primefaces, ajax, js or something else?

Thanks!
Sami

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works only if the bean is `@ViewScoped` and if you return `null` or `void` from action method.

If you return non-`null` or `void`, such as follows

```
// Back to same page!
return "newRma";
```

then a brand new view scoped bean instance will be created, hereby trashing the initial one.

Further, I'm not sure why you used `immediate="true"` on the second button, this makes no sense, but are you aware that this way the data of non-`immediate` inputs won't be processed at all and thus you should do it with the data of the previous non-`immediate` submit?

By the way, the way how you collected submitted data makes also no sense. You don't need to traverse the request parameter map (you used an invalid parameter name by the way). Just directly access the bean properties which are been bound to input values.

Comment: Immediate is an accident. Of course I tried to get value first like that: <p:column><p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.newRma_shortdesc}" for="shortdesc"/></p:column> but it is always null. So if I understood correctly it is impossible because this is not my software and this has been built using only session scoped beans? Any other solution what is working in my case? Thanks again BalusC!

Comment: Euh, the output label renders a HTML label element, not some HTML input element. Are you saying that you're using a session scoped bean for this? I do now not understand your concrete problem anymore. What exactly is your concrete functional requirement? Are you trying to get the value of a HTML label element by manually traversing the HTTP request parameter map? Are you familiar with basic HTML and HTTP?

Comment: Oh sh*t :)  <p:column><p:inputTextarea rows="4" cols="30" id="shortdesc" value="#{MainController.selected.shortdesc}" style="width: 200px;"/></p:column> Sorry, that was the correct one :) This is the only field what is not populated by MainController.haeTiedotSarjanrolla (which fetch the data via serial number) and it is for user to add/insert some extra information and now I lost that data because of that two submit button problem.

Comment: It's just available by accessing `selected.getshortdesc()` inside action method, assuming that the input field is in the same form and that the bean is at least view scoped and that the submit button doesn't have immediate="true".

Comment: Now I deleted immediate="true":s. I don't understand how that immediate=true is working. If You have just one form, two submits in one form. If you have immediate="true" in both submits, what is submitting then? If you have immediate="true" in first submit, but not in second one, what is happening then and vice versa?

Comment: A command button with `immediate="true"` will *only* process inputs which *also* have `immediate="true"`. You apparently have none. Just don't use that then.

Comment: God bless BalusC :), I owe you and yes it is working!! Still need some books? BTW, I have another problem. In that page I insert new objects to a list and then I have a table, which shows these objects. When user is addind a new object, the table is not updating, but when user is editing one field, it is updating immediately. Sessioscope and link is that:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242449/how-to-update-primefaces-datatable-every-time-when-page-is-downloaded

Comment: You're welcome. I already saw that question, but I couldn't see/understand the concrete problem immediately (too much code noise) and the question had already other answers on it, so I just ignored it. For hints in providing the "ideal" question, consider reading the "SSCCE" section of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info Also, using English instead of Finnish would have made the code much more readable to all other programmers of the world.

Comment: That wasn't my choise, Finnish I mean :) This software is not mine, I just try to make it ready. I just can't solve that table-problem, it just update when I log out and back in, but that's not so handy to users :). btw have you any good tutorial about scopes, because I have recognised that session scoped beans area just pure pain. How long for instance view-scoped bean is alive, reguesti is just one reguest but view compare to session? Session is the whole session, but...